# Put a newline after the 'Answer Your Question' button.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, answers

> **Related: ["Add Another Answer" button Bug](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/add-another-answer-button-bug)**

This doesn't look like Apple!

[image: screenshot]

The 'Answer Your Question' button overlaps the 'Notify' label and checkbox. To use this feature (I really use it) I need to turn CSS off. This sucks. Shouldn't a newline be added after this button, like on other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: what OS Version, Browser?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6.6, Safari 5.0.3 (6533.19.4).

Comment: I can repro this. The fix will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I pushed a fix to dev, it will be in the next deployment.